# Solving functional equation $\frac{f(s, t)}{f(s, m)} = \frac{1}{1+s(m-t)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-equations, mathematical-modeling

I want to find a functional equation $f(s,x)$ such that 
$$\frac{f(s, t)}{f(s, m)} = \frac{1}{1+s(m-t)}$$
If it helps the context I need this in is where $t$ is a member of a set of real number and $m$ is the maximum value of members that set. s > 0.
Not being a mathematician by background i'm not familiar with appproches to solving this and Wolfram has not provided an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this 
has any solutions
as a functional equation.

From
$\frac{f(s, t)}{f(s, m)} 
= \frac{1}{1+s(m-t)}
$,
if
$m=t+1$,
this gives
$\frac{f(s, m+1)}{f(s, m)} 
= \frac{1}{1+s}
$.

Applying this twice,
$\frac{f(s, m+2)}{f(s, m)} 
= \frac{1}{(1+s)^2}
$.

However,
setting
$m = t+2$
gives
$\frac{f(s, m+2)}{f(s, m)} 
= \frac{1}{1+2s}
$.

This is a contradiction.

Comment: Note that "$t$ is a member of a set of real number and $m$ is the maximum value of members that set". Since $m$ is a fixed real number, you can't "apply it twice".

Also, you've let $m=t+1$ which is fine but then you've used $t=m+1$!